# Unable to save NSMutableArray in NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to save an NSMutableArray on device , but everytime I reload the application the data is erased.

I tried to use NSUserDefaults but the problem persists

here is the code I am using

```
-(void) addingData{

    [data addObject:theBarcodeString]; //data is the NSMutableArray

    [mainTableView reloadData]; //this is a UITableView where the data from the NSMutableArray is populated
    [self endText];
    history=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [history        setObject:data          forKey:@"history"  ];
}
```

and here is where I load the data

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    if (data == nil) {
        data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //onload it always goes to his line

    else {

        data=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"history"  ];
    }
    ...
}
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Why are you testing `data == nil`?

Comment: to see if data was already saved in the NSMutableArray or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be testing to see if data == nil. Instead, just do:

```
data = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
    objectForKey:@"history"]];
```

Note that you will have to release that later.

If you want `data` to be a mutable array, you **must** use:

```
data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] mutableArrayValueForKey:@"history"];
```

If you try to performing mutating operations on data without using mutableArrayValueForKey, you will get a crash, because all objects returned from NSUserDefaults are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

> **synchronize** Writes any modifications to the persistent domains to disk
>   and updates all unmodified persistent domains to what is on disk.
>
> - (BOOL)synchronize
>
> Return Value YES if the data was saved successfully to disk, otherwise
>   NO.

So you have to add `[history synchronize]` to force write on the defaults

Edit: From [Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/synchronize)

> Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals,
>   use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic
>   synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or
>   if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though
>   you have not made any changes.

So if you want to save changes immediately call `[history synchronize]`.

Comment: You usually shouldn't have to call -synchronize yourself. From the docs: `The synchronize method, which is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, keeps the in-memory cache in sync with a user’s defaults database.`

Comment: I usually never call sync except for in applicationWillTerminate

Comment: It's probably a good habit to get into, and safer, but usually isn't the cause of consistent problems like this one.